# Is there a regex to recursively modify a list and change its elements in python3?

Tags: python, regex, list

I have a list of strings in the following format:

```
["6,7",
"6-8",
"10,12",
"15-18"]
```

I need to split the strings into separate elements. If `,` is there, I just need to split the element. If `-` is there, I need to generate a range of numbers to include the numbers in between.

Example: `'6,7'` gets split into `['6','7']` while `'6-8'` gets changed into `['6','7','8']`

I wrote this function which works great for this:

```
def process_nums(verse_nums_):
     if ',' in verse_nums_:
         verse_nums = [i for i in map(str.strip,verse_nums_.split(','))]
     elif '-' in verse_nums_:
         beg_end = [int(i) for i in map(str.strip,verse_nums_.split('-'))]
         verse_nums = [i for i in range(beg_end[0],beg_end[1]+1)]
     else:
         verse_nums = [verse_nums_]
     return verse_nums
```

However I got stuck with a string: `'6-8,10'`. This should be changed to `['6','7','8','10']`. I can do the initial splitting to get `['6-8','10']`.

I have written a slightly round about code to get through:

```
verse_nums = process_nums('6-8,10')

        for x in verse_nums:
            if '-' in x:
                verse_nums.extend(process_nums(x))
                verse_nums.pop(verse_nums.index(x))
        verse_nums = [int(i) for i in verse_nums].sort()
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Note:
I am not sure how to frame the question properly in the title. Kindly feel free to modify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're pretty close. No regex required. What I would do is always split on a comma, then the new parts either contain a range or are single items.

```
def process_nums(nums):
  parts = nums.split(',')
  for part in parts:
    if '-' in part:
      a, b = part.split('-')
      yield from (str(i) for i in range(int(a), int(b)+1))
    else:
      yield part

print(list(process_nums('6-8,10')))
```

Answer (score 1):

IMO regex is better, because `str.split` might not detect invalid input like: ",-,-2"

```
import re
from typing import List


def process(numbers: List[str]) -> List[str]:
    output = []
    for no_idea_what_this_is in numbers:
        for value in no_idea_what_this_is.split(","):
            match = re.fullmatch(r"(\d+)-(\d+)", value)
            if match:
                start = int(match.group(1))
                stop = int(match.group(2)) + 1
                output.extend([str(i) for i in range(start, stop)])
            elif re.fullmatch("\d+", value):
                output.append(value)
            else:
                raise ValueError(f"Unable to parse {value}")
    return output


print(process(["4-8,10"]))
# ['4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '10']
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
mylist = ["6,7","6-8","10,12","15-18"]
new_list = []



for i in mylist :
    if ',' in i :
        splited = i.split(',')
        new_list.append(splited[0])
        new_list.append(splited[1])
    elif '-' in i :
        splited = i.split('-')
        x = range(int(splited[0]),int(splited[1])+1)
        for y in x :
            new_list.append(str(y))

print(new_list)
```

output :

```
['6', '7', '6', '7', '8', '10', '12', '15', '16', '17', '18']
```

Answer (score 0):

We can make a slight mod to code from [GENERATE LIST OF NUMBERS FROM HYPHENATED AND COMMA SEPARETED STRING LIKE "1-5,25-30,4,5" (PYTHON RECIPE)](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577279-generate-list-of-numbers-from-hyphenated-and-comma/)

Advantage of this approach (over posted) is that its ability to handle more complex ranges with overlaps such as:

For:

```
'2,3,4-8,2-5,9'
```

Produces

```
['2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
```

While the accepted solution produces

```
['2', ' 3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '2', '3', '4', '5', ' 9']
```

Which has repeated indexes

```
def hyphen_range(s):
    """ Takes a range in form of "a-b" and generate a list of numbers between a and b inclusive.
    Also accepts comma separated ranges like "a-b,c-d,f" will build a list which will include
    Numbers from a to b, a to d and f"""
    s= "".join(s.split())#removes white space
    r= set()
    for x in s.split(','):
        t=x.split('-')
        if len(t) not in [1,2]: raise SyntaxError("hash_range is given its argument as "+s+" which seems not correctly formatted.")
        r.add(int(t[0])) if len(t)==1 else r.update(set(range(int(t[0]),int(t[1])+1)))
    l=list(r)
    l.sort()
    return list(map(str, l))  # added string conversion

# Test shows handling of overlapping ranges and commas in pattern
# i.e. '2, 3, 4-8, 2-5, 9'
for x in ["6,7", "6-8", "10,12", "15-18", '6-8,10', '2, 3, 4-8, 2-5, 9']:
  print(f"'{x}' -> {hyphen_range(x)}")
```

**Output**

```
'6,7' -> ['6', '7']
'6-8' -> ['6', '7', '8']
'10,12' -> ['10', '12']
'15-18' -> ['15', '16', '17', '18']'6-8,10' -> ['6', '7', '8', '10']
'6-8,10' -> ['6', '7', '8', '10']
'2, 3, 4-8, 2-5, 9' -> ['2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
```

**Generator Version**

```
def hyphen_range_generator(s):
    """ yield each integer from a complex range string like "1-9,12, 15-20,23"

    >>> list(hyphen_range('1-9,12, 15-20,23'))
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 12, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 23]

    >>> list(hyphen_range('1-9,12, 15-20,2-3-4'))
    Traceback (most recent call last):
        ...
    ValueError: format error in 2-3-4
    """
    for x in s.split(','):
        elem = x.split('-')
        if len(elem) == 1: # a number
            yield int(elem[0])
        elif len(elem) == 2: # a range inclusive
            start, end = map(int, elem)
            for i in range(start, end+1):
                yield str(i)  # only mod to posted software
        else: # more than one hyphen
            raise ValueError('format error in %s' % x)

# Need to use list(...) to see output since using generator
for x in ["6,7", "6-8", "10,12", "15-18", '6-8,10', '2, 3, 4-8, 2-5, 9']:
  print(f"'{x}' -> {list(hyphen_range_generator(x))}")
```

**Output**

```
Same as the non-generator version above
```